# Initialize object in @Shared or setupSpec()

Tags: initialization, shared, spock

What's the difference between:

```
@Shared
MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
```

and

```
MyObject myObject

def setupSpec() {
    myObject = new MyObjec()
}
```

Why should I use the @Shared annotation in the second example? Both are only created once, aren't they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your second example, you probably got this error:

> Error:(22, 9) Groovyc: Only @Shared and static fields may be accessed from here

So you can choose one of those options:

1. use `@Shared` annotation and init field in one line

   ```
    @Shared
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
   ```
2. use `static` and init field in one line

   ```
    static MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
   ```
3. use `@Shared` annotation and init field inside `setupSpec` method

   ```
    @Shared
    MyObject myObject

    def setupSpec() {
        myObject = new MyObject()
    }
   ```
4. use `static` and init field inside `setupSpec` method

   ```
    static MyObject myObject

    def setupSpec() {
        myObject = new MyObject()
    }
   ```

Comment: But do I have to use @Shared in the second example if I reference a member variable in the setupSpec() ?

Comment: @GarfieldKlon I edited my answer. I hope now is more cleaner.